# Downloading data from server and add this data to local database with sync

Tags: android, client-server, realm

I'm developing my app, in which storing quotes.
Data about quotes I download from my server.
I want in order to user downloading 10 quotes (at that time data add to local database), and if he scrolled this 10 quotes, new data will be download (again 10).
For example, as in facebook tape (with adding data to local db).
But I also need sync local db with server db.
I do not understand how to combine all this.

**Download data** -  Here I pass the id from which to download from the id from server db.

```
class DownloadAndParseJson extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<QuoteObject>> {

    interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(ArrayList<QuoteObject> output);
    }

    private AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    DownloadAndParseJson(AsyncResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    private static final String TAG = "###" + "DownloadAndParseJson";

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<QuoteObject> doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting download quotes from " + params[0] + " id");
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        int id = params[0];

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String countriesJsonStr = null;

        try {
            final String BASIC_URL = "http://*******.com";
            final String ID_PARAM = "id";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASIC_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(ID_PARAM, Integer.toString(id))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            countriesJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            Log.v(TAG, "download end");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
            return null;
        } finally {

            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
                }
            }
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "End download quotes");
        return getArrayParsedJson(countriesJsonStr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<QuoteObject> result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Downloaded " + result.size() + " quotes");
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }

    private  ArrayList<QuoteObject> getArrayParsedJson(String jsonStr){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<QuoteObject>>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonStr, collectionType);
    }
}
```

**Working with the database** - here Im store Quote objects

```
public class RealmHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "###" + "RealmHelper";
    Context context;

    public RealmHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void write(ArrayList<QuoteObject> quoteObjectArrayList) {

        Realm.init(context);
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();

        for (QuoteObject quoteObject : quoteObjectArrayList){
            realm.copyToRealm(quoteObject);
        }
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    public ArrayList<QuoteObject> read() {

        Realm.init(context);
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        return new ArrayList<>(realm.where(QuoteObject.class).findAll());
    }

    public void delete() {
        Realm.init(context);
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final RealmResults<QuoteObject> countries = realm.where(QuoteObject.class).findAll();

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                countries.deleteAllFromRealm();
                Log.i(TAG, "size = " + countries.size());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
       implements  DownloadAndParseJson.AsyncResponse{

        .
        .
    RVAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<QuoteObject> quoteObjectArrayList;
        .
        .

         protected void onCreate(){
       .
       .
       .
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            adapter = new RVAdapter(this, quoteObjectArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
    public void processFinish(ArrayList<QuoteObject> output) {
        if (output.size() != 0) {
            quoteObjectArrayList = output;
            Log.i(TAG, "processFinish() returned outputArray size " + output.size());
        }   else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not found quotes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**RecyclerView.Adapter** - To display quotes Im using card view.

```
class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder>
     implements  DownloadAndParseJson.AsyncResponse{

    private static final String TAG = "###" + "RVAdapter";

    private Context context;
    private boolean hasMoreItems;
    private ArrayList<QuoteObject> quoteObjectArrayList;

    RVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<QuoteObject> quoteObjectArrayList){
        this.context = context;
        this.hasMoreItems = true;
        this.quoteObjectArrayList = quoteObjectArrayList;

        Log.i(TAG, "quoteObjectArrayList = " + quoteObjectArrayList.size());

    }

    private void notifyNoMoreItems(){
        hasMoreItems = false;
        Toast.makeText(context, "No More Items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_of_quote, viewGroup, false);

        return new PersonViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Card position = " + position);

        if (position == quoteObjectArrayList.size() && hasMoreItems){
            new DownloadAndParseJson(this).execute(Integer.parseInt(quoteObjectArrayList.get(position).getId()));
        }
        holder.contentOfQuote.setText(quoteObjectArrayList.get(position).getQuote());
        holder.authorQuote.setText(quoteObjectArrayList.get(position).getAuthor());

        holder.ratingBar.setOnRatingChangeListener(new MaterialRatingBar.OnRatingChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(MaterialRatingBar ratingBar, float rating) {
                //ratingBar.setRight(Integer.parseInt(quoteObjectArrayList.get(position).getId()));
            }
        });

        holder.btnShareQuote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, holder.contentOfQuote.getText()
                                                + "\n" + holder.authorQuote.getText() );
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                context.startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.btnViewComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //View Comments
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return quoteObjectArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(ArrayList<QuoteObject> output) {
        if (output.size() != 0) {
            quoteObjectArrayList.addAll(output);
            Log.i(TAG, "Total quoteArray Size = " + quoteObjectArrayList.size());
            new RealmHelper(context).write(output); // NEED separate throw
        } else notifyNoMoreItems();
    }

    static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cardView;

        TextView contentOfQuote, authorQuote;

        MaterialRatingBar ratingBar;

        ImageButton btnViewComment, btnShareQuote;
        TextView rating;

        public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

            this.contentOfQuote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentOfQuote);
            this.authorQuote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.authorQuote);

            this.btnViewComment = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnViewComment);
            this.btnShareQuote = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnShareQuote);

            this.ratingBar = (MaterialRatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            this.rating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRating);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to combine all this.

It should turn out:

1. To start with the data from local db.

   - If there is no data - download new (10 quotes).
   - Else take data from local db until they run out
2. Download 10 quotes from server bd, add to local and display they.
   Or If there is no data Print out about it.
3. Sync local bd with server.

Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: use content provider and set limit in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much easier if you used RealmResults as intended along with RealmChangeListener and Realm's notification system. See the [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications).

```
class DownloadAndParseJson extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
    DownloadAndParseJson(){
    }

    private static final String TAG = "###" + "DownloadAndParseJson";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting download quotes from " + params[0] + " id");
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        int id = params[0];
        try {
            final List<QuoteObject> quotes = retrofitService.getQuotes(id).execute().body();
            if(quotes == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Download failed");
            }
            try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        realm.insert(quotes);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
            return null;
        } 
        Log.i(TAG, "End download quotes");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void ignored) {
    }
}
```

And

```
class RVAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<QuoteObject, RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "###" + "RVAdapter";

    RVAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<QuoteObject> quotes) {
        super(quotes, true);
    }

    // onCreateViewHolder

    // onBindViewHolder

    // view holder
}
```

And

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
adapter = new RVAdapter(realm.where(QuotesObject.class).findAll()); // <-- RealmResults
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and some "did download all" kind of logic, although that needs a bit smarter error handling; and "is data being downloaded" so that you don't spam requests when you scrolled down.

Comment: Great answer.  The point is to exploit Realm, which already does much of this for you, behind your back, instead of trying to force it to implement a different pattern.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you.
But I did not find anything in your answer about database synchronization on the server and in my application. In the case where I edit the quote on the server.

Comment: your options are websockets and push notifications